# Where to find out more about $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}(n-j)^k $?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find more info about the sum

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}(n-j)^k$$

where $1\leq k<n$ but am coming up short... I've tried going through all the resources I can think of but haven't found any mention of it.

Comment: The special case of $k=2$ leads to https://oeis.org/A001788.  You might find generalizations to other $k$ in the links there.

Comment: By symmetry, it is equal to $$\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj j^k$$

Answer (score 6):

We have

$$\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} (n-j)^k
= \sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} j^k
= k! [z^k] \sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} \exp(jz)
\\= k! [z^k] (1+\exp(z))^n
= k! [z^k] (2+\exp(z)-1)^n
\\ = k! [z^k] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} 2^{n-q}
(\exp(z)-1)^q
= \sum_{q=0}^k
{n\choose q} 2^{n-q} q! {k\brace q}.$$

Here we have lowered the upper range from $n$ to $k$ because $k\le n$
and $(\exp(z)-1)^q = z^q + \cdots.$

We get for $k=2$

$${n\choose 0} 2^n 0! {2\brace 0}
+ {n\choose 1} 2^{n-1} 1! {2\brace 1}
+ {n\choose 2} 2^{n-2} 2! {2\brace 2}
\\ = n 2^{n-1} + n(n-1) 2^{n-2}
= 2^{n-2} n (n+1).$$

We have for $k=3$

$${n\choose 0} 2^n 0! {3\brace 0}
+ {n\choose 1} 2^{n-1} 1! {3\brace 1}
+ {n\choose 2} 2^{n-2} 2! {3\brace 2}
+ {n\choose 3} 2^{n-3} 3! {3\brace 3}
\\ = n 2^{n-1} + n(n-1) 2^{n-2} \times 3
+ n(n-1)(n-2) 2^{n-3}
=  2^{n-3} n^2 (n+3).$$

An alternate expression is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{q=0}^k
n^{\underline{q}} 2^{n-q} {k\brace q}.}$$

Writing it like this means we get the correct answer $2^n$ when we put $k=0$ because ${0\brace 0} = 1.$

Comment: What are $z$, $[z]$, and curly-binomial-coefficient?

Comment: The curlies are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and $[z^k]$ is a [coefficient extractor for formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).